# Why is the this. qualifier required when invoking an interfaceextension method inside a class that implements the interface?

Tags: c#, interface, extension-methods

Given interface

```
public interface IHaveError
{
    string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Extension

```
public static class HaveErrorExtensions
{
    public static void SetErrorMessage(this IHaveError target, string message)
    {
        target.ErrorMessage = message;
    }
}
```

Class

```
public class HaveError : IHaveError
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.SetErrorMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Why is `this.` required on the call to the extension method? The name is not resolved without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how extension methods work in the C# language spec.  If you read section "7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations", it basically says that you must have a method invocation of one of the following forms:

```
expr . identifier ( )
expr . identifier ( args )
expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )
expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )
```

If you note, `expr` is *required* for an extension method search to be an option.

In this case, `this.` becomes the `expr.` above, so that the above can get translated into the static method invocation for a type where it's an extension method defined as:

```
C . indentifier ( expr , args )
```

In your case, in order for the compiler to "find" (or even search for) the method call, you need to have some "expr" type specified.  The explicit `this.` qualifies.  It causes the compiler to take this:

```
this.SetErrorMessage(message);
```

And search for a matching extension method that works with the type, translating it into:

```
HaveErrorExtensions.SetErrorMessage(this, message);
```

Answer (score 4):

Extension methods are merely static methods with some syntactical sugar (very yummy syntactical sugar!) applied by the compiler. The object reference the method is being called 'on' is actually the first argument of the method.

The compiler needs to know what instance you mean. It can not guess.

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` refers to the current object that you are working with.  Without `this` the compiler doesn't know on what to apply the extension method to.